# Slicing and re-indexing multidimensional dataset

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

following is a simplified version of a dataset I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(123)

times = range(10)
a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]).reshape(10,1)
b = np.array([0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]).reshape(10,1)
val1 = np.random.randn(10,1)
val1 = np.append(val1,a,1)
val2 = np.random.randn(10,1)
val2 = np.append(val2,b,1)

ds = xr.Dataset({'1st': (('time', 'attr'), val1),
                 '2nd': (('time', 'attr'), val2)},
                {'time': times, 'attr': ['val', 'mode']})
```

What I try to do, is to create a pandas dataframe of variables '1st' and '2nd', filtered only according to mode == 1, and have all the data aligned to the left (i.e - both columns of the dataframe start at index 0 and the shorter column will have some NaNs at the end).

here is my not so successful take on it:

```
mask = ds.sel(attr='mode')==1
maskedds = ds.where(mask)
maskedds = maskedds.dropna('time',how='all')
maskedds = maskedds.reset_index('time',drop=True)
test = maskedds.sel(attr='val').to_dataframe()
```

I could clear the resulting data in pandas, but my actual data is much much larger and I'm looking for a convenient slicing and reindexing done in xarray.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit:
Well, if you'll look at my original post - I constructed the 'test' dataframe which contains:

```
attr       2nd       1st
time                         
0     val -0.094709       NaN
1     val  1.491390       NaN
2     val -0.638902       NaN
3     val -0.443982       NaN
4     val       NaN -0.428913
5     val       NaN  1.265936
6     val       NaN -0.866740
```

What I'm looking after is something like this:

```
attr       2nd       1st
time                         
0     val -0.094709 -0.428913
1     val  1.491390  1.265936
2     val -0.638902 -0.866740
3     val -0.443982       NaN
4     val       NaN       NaN
5     val       NaN       NaN
6     val       NaN       NaN
```

Which i got by manually cleaning the Nans like this:

```
nonan = test['1st'].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
test['1st'] = nonan
```

But since my actual data is quite large, I'm looking for an elegant way of doing this utilizing the xarray library (otherwise I can work with multiple pandas dataframes manually...)

Comment: You can do all your per variable manipulations in xarray instead of pandas using the similar `reset_index()` and `dropna()` methods. But I can't think of any way to avoid looping over variables like you do with pandas, because you're trying to do an operation that removes alignment from your data, and neither xarray nor pandas are desigend to make that easy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately clear to me what you're going after (an example would help), but I think this is pretty close:

```
In [13]: ds.sel(attr='val').where(ds.sel(attr='mode')).to_dataframe()
Out[13]:
           1st       2nd
time
0          NaN       NaN
1          NaN -0.094709
2          NaN  1.491390
3          NaN -0.638902
4          NaN -0.443982
5          NaN       NaN
6          NaN       NaN
7    -0.428913       NaN
8     1.265936       NaN
9    -0.866740       NaN
```

If you don't like the empty rows, you can use `.dropna()` and/or `.reset_index()` in xarray or pandas:

```
In [16]: ds.sel(attr='val').where(ds.sel(attr='mode')).dropna('time', how='all').to_dataframe()
Out[16]:
           1st       2nd
time
1          NaN -0.094709
2          NaN  1.491390
3          NaN -0.638902
4          NaN -0.443982
7    -0.428913       NaN
8     1.265936       NaN
9    -0.866740       NaN
```

Comment: I edited my first post with an example of what I am looking for